# How to pass call a dynamic method instead of static method in data-ng-click (i.e want to pass a method to be called instead of fixed delete() method)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
angular.module('Testmodule').directive
('mymodalwindow', function () {   
 return {

        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div class="modal" id="mytestModal" role="dialog"  aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">' +
     '       <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm ">' +
    '                <div class="modal-content">' +
      '              <div class="modal-header">' +
       '                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirmation</h4>' +
        '            </div>' +`enter code here`
         '           <div class="modal-body">' +
         '              Do you want to delete the {{screenname}} "{{selecteditemtest}}" ?' + 
           '         </div>' +
            '        <div class="modal-footer">' + 

             '           <button type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="delete()"data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>' +
              '          <button type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>' +
               '     </div>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>'
    };
});
```

//How to call a method passed as parameters instead of calling the fixed method in data-ng-click

Comment: Probably it's better if you call the same method `delete()` with a dynamic parameter like `delete(myparam)`

Comment: I want to use this directive in several places, so the method name delete() might not be same everywhere.(i.e it might be delete(), Deletedata() etc). In that case i wont be able to reuse this directive.

Comment: Call it `directiveAction()` and pass a param to specify the action to do `directiveAction('deleteItem', item)` and `directiveAction('deleteData', item)`, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div my-modal-window on-delete="onDelete()"></div> //You can pass params here . onDelete() function can be any function in your controller
```

Directive code

```
    angular.module('Testmodule').directive('mymodalwindow', function () {
    return {

        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            onDelete: '&'
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.delete = function () {
                scope.onDelete(); // You can pass parameter like scope.onDelete({param1:'dsadasd',param2:'sadasjdlkjakl'}); 
            }
        },
        template: '<div class="modal" id="mytestModal" role="dialog"  aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">' +
            '       <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm ">' +
            '                <div class="modal-content">' +
            '              <div class="modal-header">' +
            '                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirmation</h4>' +
            '            </div>' + `enter code here`
        '           <div class="modal-body">' +
        '              Do you want to delete the {{screenname}} "{{selecteditemtest}}" ?' +
        '         </div>' +
        '        <div class="modal-footer">' +

        '           <button type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="delete()"data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>' +
        '          <button type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>' +
        '     </div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>'
    };
});
```

Comment: Am using this directive at different places, so in 1 controller the name of delete method is deletedata(id), and in another place the delete method is deleteTest(id), so will it work if both the controllers have different name for methods?

Comment: both works <div my-modal-window on-delete=" deleteTest(id)"></div> and <div my-modal-window on-delete=" deletedata(id)"></div

Comment: And how to pass the onDelete method? so onDelete will be actually what? how i will pass the method to be called to the directive? Lets say am calling this direcive at some place like  <mymodalwindow></mymodalwindow> then how it will know which method need to be called at data-ng-click event of button delete ?

Comment: <mymodalwindow on-delete="youMethod()"></mymodalwindow>

Comment: Great, enjoy. let me know if you have any issue